# Keras video frame prediction with lower output dimension then input dimension

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I want to train a Keras DNN for video frame prediction:

- **Input**: 4 consecutive Frames of a Video
- **Output**: Next frame, predicted from the network

So, basically, the dimensions are: input: (number_samples, 4, 60, 60), output: (number_samples, 1, 60, 60). **I need some help in getting from the 4 frames in the input down to 1 frame in the output**.

I've found [an example here](http://https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py) and would like to work with that.

Problem is, in that network, the output is not one frame, but the same number of frames as the input. (so my task is actually simpler, because I want to generate only one next frame, not 4). **Now I don't know, which layers I could append at the end of the network or how I could change the network, so the output dimensions are as desired.** (one frame instead of 4).

Appending a Conv2D Layer at the end did not work, because it does not match with the dimensions of the Conv3D.

Any Ideas on how to go about that problem and how my network architecture could look like? Any advice on my task in general and how I could build a good network for it is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop in the code example (for which you gave the URL) can be tailored to do what you desire.

```
for j in range(16):
    new_pos = seq.predict(track[np.newaxis, ::, ::, ::, ::])
    new = new_pos[::, -1, ::, ::, ::]
track = np.concatenate((track, new), axis=0)
```